# PYZT Timezones Are Incorrect

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am running the following

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Jan 1 2017", "%b %d %Y").replace(tzinfo=timezone("US/Central")).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'2017-01-01T00:00:00-0551'
```

I would expect this to be at an offset of -0600, but it seems to be off by 9 minutes. Why is this timezone wrong and how do I get it to correct?

Comment: `pyzt`? Are you sure is not `pytz`? If it is `pytz`, what version? I can't reproduce on Python 3.5 and `pytz==2017.3` (and MacOS Sierra 10.12.6)

Comment: Probably you meant `pytz("US/Central")` instead of `timezone("US/Central")`? Also please add your imports too with your sample code, looks like somthing is off

Comment: @BorrajaX It is pyzt. python 3.5 pyzt 2017.3

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri The pytz docs say to use timezone. When I try pytz it crashes.